# Init Script not running from PWD

Tags: centos, init-script

I have installed gunicorn webserver and make gunicorn virtualenv init.d script but when i run `service gunicorn start` service from my project directory it works well, But when my present working directory changed such as /root or anyother directory it gives me error. I have edited init script and add following command at start of that script `cd /root/demoproject/` script runs from any working directory. What else will be the actual solution other that adding `cd /root/demoproject/` command in init script ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with letting the script change its working directory, if it needs to be run with a specific working directory (due to it using relative paths, or whatever it does).

The only thing that one may want to do is to exit with a non-zero exit status if the `cd` failed:

```
cd /root/demoproject || exit 1
```

You may also change directory in the script depending on the value of an environment variable:

```
cd "${MY_WORK_DIR:-/root/demoproject}" || exit 1
```

This would change working directory to the directory given by `MY_WORK_DIR`, but would default to `/root/demoproject` if this variable is empty or unset.

Comment: I have edited the question, Actually i want to know Is there anything possible to make env variable instead of adding `cd /root/demoproject/` in init script ?

Comment: @blaCkninJa See updated answer.